# Share file from Android with PC and Verse versa via wifi Hotspot

Tags: android, android-wifi, file-transfer

Basically, what i need are reference materials or online tutorials on how to share files with my PC from my android files as it is done in [WiFi file transfer pro](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro&ei=CeE6U6joCqSf0QW2xIHgCQ&usg=AFQjCNE28IGakVGVBrOc5ISkh0-EUU0Bpg&sig2=u8z99d9BxCtzV_6LIdOABg&bvm=bv.63934634,d.d2k). What are the android technologies i need to know to be able to implement something like that. This question might be a bit broad, but i am a beginner and i really want to know how to go about doing something like that as i am to implement something related in my mid-term work.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two things: (1) how to connect the PC with android device over WiFi; (2) what protocols are used for file sharing.

There are multiple solutions for (1). You may connect both devices to the same WiFi router (requires an extra equipment). Or you may set one device as an AP and let the other connect to it. You may also use the ad hoc mode. Once get connected, ping the counterpart at both ends to make sure they get connected. All you need in this step are the IP addresses for both devices (PC and android device).

For (2), you may use either http or ftp. There are free http/ftp server on Android market that you can use directly. Once the server is done, access the server on you PC with IE and with the correct IP address/port number. You may also design your own server and client SW with customized UI and novel functions.

You can realize this solution with no programming jobs. Alternatively, if you want source codes, try the keywords http/ftp, server/client.

Besides this solution, you may also utilize the cloud service like Dropbox. Simply install Dropbox on both devices with the same account. They will see each other and synchronize files automatically. No programming job. Drawback is the need of Internet access at both ends.